# Field filter in Report layout - Attribute table view of QGIS

Tags: qgis, reports

In a report layout, I want to filter the fields where `"Changed Field" not in ('geometry')`. How do I do this without creating a filter on the main dataset?

[image]

Comment: which version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: v 3.22.3. I tried the statement in the data override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer. There's a field filter under the 'Feature Filtering' group.

[image]